# Font advice for a rookie

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm making a little flyer in Adobe InDesign based on an nice flyer I've found. I'm used to use only 2 different types of fonts. But my example has 3 different fonts. One for main title, one for smaller title and one for the plain text.

I want to use fonts like Segoe UI, Bebas and Myriad. But I don't know which font I need to use for my title, smaller title and body text. Can someone give advice?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid this is just to broad and opinion based. I've voted to close it. There are no "rules" and any answers would be purely speculation based on *that* users opinion.

Comment: I will change my question in a few minutes.

Comment: How can I delete my post? I changed my question to a more specific question in a new post.

Comment: @ThomasCovem: If you are registered, you should see a delete button under your question. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/255554) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid using too much bold or thick & tall fonts for the main body text because it's hard to read, and at small size it will look like a block of black text. So you can already know Bebas might not work well there.

But Bebas looks awesome for titles or subtitles, and is very easy to read.

The logic you should use to select the right font is to make sure the title will be eye catching; you get this effect by using a big thin font or you can use a bold font and uppercase like Bebas.

The important is that when you lay your text with the font style, the first attention grabber should be the main titles, then the subtitles and then people will read the body text if you got them interested. In general, fonts with s bit of serif are easier to read for the body text. If you have a lot of text, you might prefer to use some sans-serif for the titles and serif or semi-serif for your body text.

So work around that guide to select the best choice of font for you!

And just a tip, try to not use too many fonts and play with the style instead (eg. uppercase, bold, thin, condensed, color, etc.) Using 2-3 fonts is alright but make sure if you use 3 fonts it adds to your layout and doesn't look unbalanced.